# Failed to install hashlib, python 3, debian

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

The software fails to install. Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

I believe that the error is probably a dependency error.

```
             Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-9rlb94_r/hashlib/setup.py) egg_info for package hashlib
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
                from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, map
              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
                from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
                import email.parser
              File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
                from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
              File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
                from email import message
              File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
                from email import utils
              File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
                import random
              File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 45, in <module>
                from hashlib import sha512 as _sha512
              File "/tmp/pip-build-9rlb94_r/hashlib/hashlib.py", line 80
                raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"
                                ^
            SyntaxError: invalid syntax
            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
            Traceback (most recent call last):

          File "<string>", line 3, in <module>

          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

            from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, map

          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

            from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter

          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>

            import email.parser

          File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>

            from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser

          File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>

            from email import message

          File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>

            from email import utils

          File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>

            import random

          File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 45, in <module>

            from hashlib import sha512 as _sha512

          File "/tmp/pip-build-9rlb94_r/hashlib/hashlib.py", line 80

            raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"

                            ^

        SyntaxError: invalid syntax

        ----------------------------------------
```

I am using this library to generate hashes for files and so alternative solutions would also be welcome.

Comment: The error us due to the Python 2 syntax `raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"`, which in Python 3 is written `raise ValueError("unsupported hash type")`. What command are you issuing to install hashlib?

Comment: pip3 install hashlib :)

Comment: According to [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashlib/20081119), hashlib is for Python 2.4 and below. Python 2.5 and above comes with hashlib included. To see for yourself, try to `import hashlib`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`hashlib` module is installed by default (I think Python 2.6+). You are trying to install a backport of it created for forward compatibility of old Python versions.

Just do `import hashlib` and do your stuff.

You could find info about packages by searching in https://pypi.python.org/pypi.

Comment: Hashlib does not show up in pip list. It does get import though, any idea?

Comment: @user219628 It's a part of Python. You don't need to install it nor it would come up in pip list.

Comment: Agreed. If you came here because of this error appearing during a Google Cloud Function deployment, just remove the dependency from the requirements.txt file

Comment: Search for "hashlib" in the Python Standard Library.  These packages do not need to be installed.  They only need to be imported.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/